# Locally isometric map and dynamics

Tags: dynamical-systems, isometry

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,p)$ be metric spaces and $\pi : Y\rightarrow X$ be a locally isometric covering map. Let $g:X\rightarrow X$, $f: Y \rightarrow Y$ be homeomorphisms such that $\pi\circ f = g\circ \pi$. Further
Suppose that $X$ is compact and there exists $\delta_{0} >0$ such that for each $y\in Y$ and $0<\delta <\delta_{0}$, the open set $U_{\delta}(y)$ is connected and $\pi : \pi^{-1}(\pi(U_{\delta}(y)))\rightarrow U_{\delta}(\pi(y))$ is an isometry. Then show that for every pair $x_{1}\neq x_{2}\in X$, there exist $y_{1}, y_{2}\in Y$ with $\pi(y_{1})=x_{1}$ and $\pi(y_{2})=x_{2}$ 
and $p(y_{1}, y_{2})= d(x_{1}, x_{2})$.

(Locally isometric covering map: Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,p)$ be metric spaces and let $\pi : Y\rightarrow X$ be a continuous map then $\pi$ is called a locally isometric covering map if for each $x\in X$, there exists a neighborhood $U(x)$ of $x$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U(x)) = \cup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}$ where $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$ is a pairwise disjoint family of open sets and $\pi|_{U_{\alpha}} : U_{\alpha}\rightarrow U(x)$ is an isometry for each $\alpha$.)

Comment: You are missing something, I believe, where you wrote "...with $d(x_1,x_2)$...".

Comment: Please see, i have update it, it was extra words. @Matthias Klupsch

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: We need to show that for every pair $x_{1}\neq x_{2}\in X$, there exist $y_{1}, y_{2}\in Y$ with $\pi(y_{1})=x_{1}$ and $\pi(y_{2})=x_{2}$ 
and $p(y_{1}, y_{2})= d(x_{1}, x_{2})$

Comment: Why did you introduce $f$ and $g$? They are not mentioned again.

Comment: Also, if the degree of the covering map $\pi$ is greater than one then this hypothesis is never true: "there exists $\delta_{0} >0$ such that for each $y\in Y$ and $0<\delta <\delta_{0}$, the open set $U_{\delta}(y)$ is connected and $\pi : \pi^{-1}(\pi(U_{\delta}(y)))\rightarrow U_{\delta}(\pi(y))$ is an isometry", because for sufficiently small $\delta$ the set $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_\delta(y)))$ will always be disconnected.

Comment: Hypothesis are given in literature for proving bigger theorem. So, i mention $f$ and $g$ as it is a possibilty that hypothrsis can be use to obtain the neughborhood in which $\pi$ will become isometry and existence of the fact that i asked, can be prove.

Comment: @Lee Mosher will you please give me some example contradicting the hypothesis or some reference?

Comment: For every covering map of degree $\ge 2$, and every $U(x) \subset X$ with $\pi^{-1}(U(x)) = \cup_\alpha U_\alpha$ as in your discussion of locally isometric covering maps, if you pick one $\alpha_0$, choose $y \in U_{\alpha_0}$, and choose $\delta>0$ so small that $U_\delta(y) \subset U_{\alpha_0}$, then the restricted map $\pi : \pi^{-1}(\pi(U_\delta(y))) \to \pi(U_\delta(y))$ is not injective, because each point $x \in \pi(U_\delta(y))$ has as one pre-image for each $\alpha$, and there are $\ge 2$ values of $\alpha$. But a non-injective map cannot be an isometry.